# using partial view in a view and getting data to partial view

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am using a partial view "_studentList" in a View "SearchStudent". In my View i have a textfield and a search button and i am showing list of students in my partial view.
My View is like as follow:

```
    @model Practice_SQL_Validation_ALL.Models.SearchViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "SearchStudent";
     }

     <h2>SearchStudent</h2>

     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Search</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtserch" placeholder="Enter Roll No or Name">
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SEARCHCRITERA.VALUE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Roll No or Name" } })*@
                </div>
                <button id="preview" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>
         </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
       </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
   <div id="result">
        @Html.Partial("_StudentList", Model.STUDENTLIST)
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.ready(function () {
        $("#result").hide();
        $("#preview").click(function () {
            //$("#div1").hide();
            $("#result").show();
        });
    });



    $("#preview").click(function () {
        var jsonObject = {
            "returnUrl": $('#txtserch').val()
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SearchStudent",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
            success: function (data) { alert("Success"); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my Partial View is like as follow:

```
@model IEnumerable<Practice_SQL_Validation_ALL.Models.Student>

@*<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>*@
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ROLLNUMBER)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ADDRESS)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PHONE)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CLASS)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ISNEW)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ROLLNUMBER)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ADDRESS)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PHONE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CLASS)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ISNEW)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My ViewModel is like as follow:

```
namespace Practice_SQL_Validation_ALL.Models
{
    public class SearchViewModel
    {
        private SearchCriteria searchcriteria = null;
        private List<Student> studentlist = null;

        public SearchCriteria SEARCHCRITERA 
        {
            set
            {
                searchcriteria = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return searchcriteria;
            }
        }

        public List<Student> STUDENTLIST 
        {
            set
            {
                studentlist = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return studentlist;
            }
        }

        public SearchViewModel()
        {
            searchcriteria = new SearchCriteria();
            studentlist = new List<Student>();
        }
    }

    public class SearchCriteria
    {
        [Display(Name = "Criteria")]
        public string CRITERIA { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Value")]
        public string VALUE { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        #region Properties
        private bool m_isnew = true;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Roll Number")]
        public string ROLLNUMBER { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string NAME { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string ADDRESS { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone#")]
        public string PHONE { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Class")]
        public string CLASS { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Edit Mode")]
        public bool ISNEW { get { return m_isnew; } set { m_isnew = value; } }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

My StudentController is as follow:

```
namespace Practice_SQL_Validation_ALL.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SearchStudent()
        {
            SearchViewModel obj = new SearchViewModel();
            ViewBag.Count = 0;
            return View(obj);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        //[AllowAnonymous]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        //[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult SearchStudent(string returnUrl)
        {
            SearchViewModel obj = new SearchViewModel();
            //DAS db = new DAS();
            //list = db.SearchStudentwithCriteria("RollNo", "");
            //return PartialView()
            obj.SEARCHCRITERA.VALUE = "Some";
            obj.STUDENTLIST.Add(new Student { ADDRESS = "Address", ROLLNUMBER = "3160", NAME = "Awais", CLASS = "A", PHONE = "Phone" });
            //return View(list);
            ViewBag.Count = obj.STUDENTLIST.Count;
            //return View(obj);
            return PartialView("_StudentList", obj);
            //return PartialView("_StudentList", list);
            //return PartialView("_StudentList", list);
        }
    }
}
```

I want that if I click search button then ajax call SearchStudent Post function and return collection that should be displayed on partial view. Till now function is being called but response is not being returned to the view or partialview. As i am showing alertbox in both cases success and failure but system does not show alertbox in anycase. What am i doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more information.

Very Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes as follow and got my issue fixed.

```
In Controller function "SearchStudent" returned partialview with collection.

public ActionResult SearchStudent(string returnUrl)
        {
            SearchViewModel obj = new SearchViewModel();
            obj.SEARCHCRITERA.VALUE = "Some";
            obj.STUDENTLIST.Add(new Student { ADDRESS = "Address", ROLLNUMBER = "3160", NAME = "Awais", CLASS = "A", PHONE = "Phone" });
            ViewBag.Count = obj.STUDENTLIST.Count;

            return PartialView("_StudentList", obj.STUDENTLIST);
        }
```

And changed ajax call as follow:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SearchStudent",
            //dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            //context:
            contentType: "html",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
            success: function (data) { $("#result").html(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                $("#result").html("Error");
            }
        });
```

I think problem was majorly in ajax call. As i was returning html content from controller function but in ajax call i have mentained contentType and datatype properties as Json. That's why HTML could not been shown on success.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine just the ajax succes you have to put the content like this

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "SearchStudent",
            data: { "returnUrl": $('#txtserch').val()},
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").html(data);   //********* This is where you have put the result into, because in success you will get the HTML
            },
            error: function () {

            }            
        });
```

Comment: made same changes but nothing happend. breakpoint hits in function and value of "returnUrl" is also correct in function but nothing is being updated on partialview.

Comment: I am now returning json abject from my controller function. now it is showing alert box on success.

`return Json(new { result = obj.STUDENTLIST});`

but i am still unable to show STUDENTLIST data in partial view. Any kind of help will be strongly appriciated.

Comment: Thank you so much @Anil Panwar for your kind help. :)

Comment: You need to check datatype, this will fix ,see i have not added it in the sample.